# Accessing Google Calendar using API v3

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm attempting to rewrite a legacy application which I didn't write previously using the Google Calendar v3 API.

I've implemented the google-api-php-client, created an API key in my developer console and gone through the process to authenticate. I've got an `accessToken` which I'm persisting in the database and when it expires, I can refresh that token fine.

However, I'm unable to any work with the Calendars *at all*.

I'm following what limited documentation is already out there and have the following:

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->setClientId( $this->settings['clientId'] );
$this->client->setClientSecret( $this->settings['clientSecret'] );
$this->client->setAccessToken( $this->settings['accessToken'] );

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

while(true) {
foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
    echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
}

$pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();

if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
} else {
    break;
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting back is :

```
Message:  Undefined property: Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList::$items
```

I've checked my Google Calendar account and all the calendars are shared, so there should be no problem, although I don't see why that is an issue since I'm using an authenticated account anyway.

Anyone able to offer advice?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to debug your calendars list call here? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#try-it just to make sure you have a response from "$calendarList->getItems()"

Comment: Yes, it returns the calendars fine when I use the 'try it' function.

Comment: can you post the output of var_dump($calendarList->getItems()) ?

Comment: Yep, a var_dump on that returns NULL

Answer (score 2):

The Error you are getting

```
Message:  Undefined property: Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList::$items
```

Is because the object is empty

Replace

```
while(true) {
foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
    echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
}Undefined property
```

with this to get rid of the error.

```
if ($calendarList->getItems()) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
    echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();

    }
```

Also adjust the following

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
```

Needs to be

```
$client = new Google_Client();
```

Comment: That wont work either. Returns the error : "Can't use method return value in write context "

Comment: if($calendarList->getItems()){

Comment: If you replace the first line with my comment above does that fix the issue

Comment: It fixes that particular problem - but I'm still getting "Message: Undefined property: Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList::$items"

Comment: change $this->client = new Google_Client(); to $client = new Google_Client();

Comment: That makes no difference either. The annoying thing is that as a standalone PHP page, it works fine - when I add the same code into my CodeIgniter Project, it no longer works

Comment: The code you provided is invalid. By fixing the first line as i suggested it made the code work. You have a seperate issue with codeigniter.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. It appears the problem is related to the static calls in CodeIgniter... Since the code works stand alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68276/discussion-between-jon-c-and-madebyhippo).